# What can change the window.innerHeight inside an iframe?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, mobile-safari

I have a mobile game that has to be wrapped inside an `iframe`. The game page itself has code that sizes it to fit the screen normally, the requirement for an `iframe` is new.

The game page uses a canvas surrounded by `div`s, which are sized using JS to fill the space around the canvas after it has been scaled to fit the size of the screen (maintaining its aspect ratio). This gets called every couple of seconds to ensure it is still correct. This has been working for a while when not inside an `iframe`.

I've now put the game inside an `iframe`, which is set to fill the screen. This works fine on desktop, and on Android Chrome, but iOS 7 Safari on an iPad Air seems to have issues. The game shifts down by 4px every time the sizing update function is called and the top border expands. This seems to be happening because `window.innerHeight` is getting larger inside the game frame. The size of the `iframe` does not change, however.

What can cause the `iframe` to have a changing `window.innerHeight`, if the size of the `iframe` itself is not changing? I feel it's likely that some of the game code is causing the change, but I can't track down which bit, as I didn't think it was possible for `window.innerHeight` to be changed without resizing the window. I've added a resize listener to the game, and it does seem to be fired at the same rate as the sizing update, so I assume something in there is causing the `window.innerHeight` to increase.

I'm not sure if this is relevant or not, but it does seem to increase steadily to 1024px, at which point it stops increasing. This is the same value as `window.innerWidth`

Update: Just tried the same code on an iPhone 5, and have the same issue, except the end values of `innerHeight` and `innerWidth` are 783 and 568.